# Facebook APi Post to page always not allowing to post always unauthorized?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having problem integrating the facebook post to wall for pages (not user).
I have already authorized the app for all the scoop.

Scoop lists:
user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_online_presence,user_photo_video_tags,user_photos,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,email,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_requests,read_stream,xmpp_login,manage_friendlists,manage_notifications,status_update,offline_access,publish_checkins,publish_stream,rsvp_event,manage_pages

I have accepted all grant access scopes and I have successfully connected and get the users data I have save into the database the info of users available pages:
**page id and page access token**

Whe I am posting a test message It say's : **#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**

here is my login script for fb:

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({ 
       appId:'MY_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
       status:true, xfbml:true,oauth : true 
     });
   };
   (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
    //FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function() {window.location = '/logout'});     
$('#facebook_login').click(function(e) {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if(response.authResponse) {
          parent.location ='http://mywebsite.com/users/oauth_fb';
      }
 },{scope: 'user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_online_presence,user_photo_video_tags,user_photos,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,email,read_friendlists,read_insights,read_mailbox,read_requests,read_stream,xmpp_login,manage_friendlists,manage_notifications,status_update,offline_access,publish_checkins,publish_stream,rsvp_event,manage_pages'});
});
```

After connecting facebook account I will logout automatically my facebook account with my script:

```
<script>
                      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                         FB.init({ 
                           appId:'MY_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
                           status:true, xfbml:true,oauth : true 
                         });

                         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                             if (response.status === 'connected') {
                                FB.logout(function(response) {
                                     window.location = '';
                                });
                             }
                         });
                       };
                       (function(d){
                               var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                               if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                               js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                               js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js\";
                               ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
                        }(document));
                    </script>
```

And here is my script for posting (this is for offline posting so user already logged out on facebook):

```
$oauth_uid = 'PAGE_ID_FROM_DB';
$oauth_token = 'PAGE_TOKEN_FROM_DB'
$post_url = '/'.$oauth_uid.'/feed';
if ($oauth_uid) {
$msg_body = array(  
    'access_token'  => $oauth_token,                
    'message' => 'tesing post to my page',
);

try {
$postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

How to fixed this issue ? I don't see anything wrong with my script , why I can post to my personal facebook account while I  can't post on my facebook page ?

Please help..

Thank you.

Comment: Debug the access token you used to post here -  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and check the permissions

Comment: I have already debug, the permissions are match with my scope. I have already found why I can't post because I have automatically logout after logout using my javascript code above.

Comment: How can I set facebook auto logout without revoking the permission ?